# Bill of Materials: One table for everything, or a table for each sub-level?

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I am working with a client in manufacturing whose products are configurations of the same bunch of parts. I am creating a database that holds all valid products and their Bill of Materials. I need help on deciding a Bill Of Material schedule to implement.

The obvious solution is a many-to-many relationship with a junction table:

```
Table 1: Products
Table 2: Parts
Junction Table: products, parts, part quantities
```

However, there are multiple levels in my client's product;

```
-Assembly
    -Sub-Assembly
        -Component
            -Part
```

and items from lower levels are allowed to be associated with any upper level item;

```
Assembly     |Sub-assembly
Assembly     |Component
Assembly     |Part
Sub-Assembly |Component
Sub-Assembly |Part
Component    |Part
```

and I suspect the client will want to add more levels in the future when new product lines are added.

Correct me if I am wrong, but I believe the above relation schedule would demand a growing integer sequence of junction tables and queries (0+1+1+2+3...) to display and export the full Bill of Materials which may eventually affect performance.

Someone suggested to put everything in one table:

```
Table 1: Assemblies, sub-assemblies, components, parts, etc...
Junction table: Children and Parents
```

This only requires one junction table to create infinite levels of many-to-many relationships. I don't know if I trust this solution, but I can't think of any issues other than accidentally making an item its own parent and creating an infinite loop and that it sounds disorganized.

I lack the experience to determine whether either or neither of these models will work for my client. I am sketching these models in MS Access, but I am open to moving this project to a more powerful platform if necessary. Any input is appreciated. Thank you.

-M

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is a hierarchy. As such it should take the form:

part_hierarchy:

```
part_id | parent_part_id | other | attributes | of | this | relationship
```

So part_id 1 may have a parent part_id 10 "component" which may have a parent_part_id (when looked up itself in this table) of 12 "Assembly. It would look like:

```
part_id | parent_part_id
1       | 10
10      | 12
```

and parts table:

```
part_id | description
1       | widget
10      | widget component
12      | aircraft carrier
```

That's a little simplified since it doesn't take into account your product/part relationship, but it will all fit together using this methodology.

Nice and simple. Now it doesn't matter how deep the hierarchy goes. It's still just two columns (And any extra columns needed for attributes of this relationship like... `create_date`, `last_changed_by_user`, etc.

I would suggest something more powerful than access though since it lacks the ability to pick a part a hierarchy using a Recursive CTE, something that comes with SQL Server, Postgres, Oracle, and the like.

I would 100% avoid any schema that requires you to add more fields or tables as the hierarchy becomes deeper and more complex. That is a path that leads towards pain and regret.

Comment: This schema could create a lot of wasted space in the rows as attributes are added that only correspond to one level. It will also make validation problematic: when can an attribute be null, etc.

Comment: If an attribute is only applicable for a particular level then it doesn't belong in that table. These would be attributes of the relationship between the part and it's parent. Attributes for an id that is part of the relationship would belong in whatever common table one would build for the branches of this hierarchy. Perhaps there are three components to this hierarchy. Roots (parts), branches (ids purely for relationships like "Component"), and leafs (parts). Or the inverse/upside-down version of that depending on what makes sense for OP. So 4 tables.

Comment: I think a combination of your solutions will work for me. One table with all parts, one table with part type (assembly, component, etc), one join table for part/part type, and one join table for part/parent part. Wouldn't the tree structure be inferred in the part/parent part join table without need to indicate what kind of relationship it is (e.g. assembly to sub-assembly)?

Answer (score 1):

Since the level of nesting is arbitrary, use one table with a self-referencing `parent_id` foreign key to itself.

While this is technically correct, navigating it requires recursive query that most DB's don't support. However, a simple and effective way of making accessing nested parts simple is to store a "path" to each component, which looks like a path in a file system.

For example, say part id 1 is a top level part that has a child whose id is 2, and part id 2 has a child part with id 3, the paths would be:

```
id    parent_id    path
1     null         /1
2     1            /1/2
3     2            /1/2/3
```

Doing this means finding the tree of subparts for any part is simply:

```
select b.part
from parts a
join parts b on b.path like concat(a.path, '%')
where a.id = ?
```